# How to use jwsmtp on windows

Tags: c++

This may sound a little stupid but i am unable to use the downloaded library of jwsmtp on my windows machine. I am using codeblocks to write my program and am relatively new to it. I installed the cygnus and followed the instructions given on the jwsmtp site http://johnwiggins.net/jwsmtp/howto. But it is not working. How do i add the library i downloaded so that i may use its functions. Once again i apologize if i seem stupid . Can someone help me out here.

If i go to project properties and linker tab and try to see whether there are any libraries in jwsmtp there appears to be none? What exactly do i do?

When i try to compile the project  using the command

g++ mail.cpp -o Mail -IC:\Users\Desktop\jwsmtp-1.32.15 -LC:\Users\Desktop\jwsmtp-1.32.15 -ljwsmtp-1.32.15

mail.cpp no such file or directory exists.Here mail is the name of the source file and Mail the name of the code block project.
What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you link to has a command to retrieve the install location: `pkg-config --libs --cflags jwsmtp-<version>`. This should be run in the cygwin (cygnus) environment.

The second step is to pass the install location and library name to CodeBlocks. [This page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/) has a generic description; you'll have to fill in the paths that you just retrieved.

Comment: I have edited the question  .Can you please take a look at it.

Comment: You're apparently not running the `g++` command from the source directory. Either go to that directory first, or pass the full path of `mail.cpp` to G++.

Comment: I used the .configure command and make and make install .Now i am unable to find where the libraries are installed to add it to code blocks